# Comparing Saved Eastern Time Zone to Utc time

Tags: c#, azure

I have a setup like the following:

```
public class Event
{
DateTime StartTime {get;set;}
DateTime EndTime {get;set;}
}
```

A user will post a Eastern Standard Time event.

```
public Save(DateTime start,DateTime end)
{
//I now save it to UTC time
   TimeZoneInfo estZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");

var newEvent = new Event{StartTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(start, estZone

),EndTime=TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(end, estZone)};
}
```

Now if I want to compare this the current time against the time stored in the database Locally it works fine, but my UTC timed server is not working correctly. What I am asking is, is there a better way to save the times or the way I am saving it is ok, but I need a better way of pulling it out.

```
    var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
//The following line will not return anything because the server time is UTC set
    var GetStartedEvents = from e in Events where e.StartTime <= now select x
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The better way is to use `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime`. `DateTimeOffset` contains the time zone information, `DateTime` not.

Comment: A better way is to store the information in your database in UTC format. Use the `DateTimeOffset` (or an alternative date library like [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/)) to translate the stored time into the current users timezone and vice versa.

Comment: Using my demo, can you show me an example? I have read documentation and I just dont quite get it.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer the question without knowing the actual problem that you're trying to solve. But, I can tell you that coordinating and synchronizing dates across multiple timezones can get out of control quickly. My generic advice is to make the comparisons only once and store the results. What I mean is that it will probably be worth it to create DB storage for each of the relavent time conversions associated with the event.

`TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(dateValue);` will get you your local time translation AFTER you have converted the input to UTC. It is good that you look up the EST conversion each time because it will be -5:00 or -4:00 at different times of the year depending on daylight savings months.

I hope this answer helps some.